# WhereHas with WhereRaw on one to many relationship (Laravel)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have an order table and an order_details table in my system.
Relationship between order table and order details table is one to many, means One order has many order details.

Now the problem is i am trying to filter the order with the quantity of items a that are stored in order_details table.

what i doing right know trying to access with whereHas

```
if ($request->has('quantity') && $request->quantity != null){
        $query = $query->whereHas('orderDetails',function ($q) use ($request){
            $q->whereRaw('SUM(Quantity) >= '.$request->quantity);
        });
    }
$orders = $query->orderBy('OrderID','desc')->get();
```

But it throws an error

```
General error: 1111 Invalid use of group function (SQL: select * from `orders` where `AddedToCart` = 0 and `PaymentSucceeded` = 1 and exists (select * from `order_details` where `orders`.`OrderID` = `order_details`.`OrderID` and SUM(Quantity) >= 12) order by `OrderID` desc)
```

I will be vary thankful if i get the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to use `sum` function you need to `group by` data and as I see you are trying to group them by orderID.

An approach like this might help:

```
 $ordersIDs = DB::table('orderDetails')
                    ->groupBy('OrderID')
                    ->havingRaw('SUM(Quantity)', '>=', 12)
                    ->pluck('orderID')->toArray();

    $orders = DB::table('orders')
                    ->whereIn($ordersIDs)
                    ->get();
```

The above code executes two SQL queries, you can mix them easily to make one.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Exactly i did, Thanks for that